# Get Content Type and Content Disposition from internal file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a bunch of files that gets written to a directory on my server in chunks. Another function then picks up those files, merges them and pushes them to S3.

Usually when I file using a standard form, I am able to get its Content Disposition and Content Type from the header. However, with the merger function, I pick the file from the server internally. How can I get the Content Disposition and Content Type from this?

This is my conversion function from FileStream to FormFile because my push function only takes IFormFile.

```
var fsor = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FilePath);
var ff = new FormFile(fsor, 0, fsor.Length, "file[0]", fileName);
```

EDIT:

I know the Content Disposition value is supposed to be like this:

> "form-data; name=\"file[0]\"; filename=\"Ksd8554_aaaHIRD_KL.pdf\""

But so far I am unable to replicate this string due to the slashes and the surrounding quotations.

Comment: If you're just manually creating a `FormFile` like that, you'll probably have to set the values yourself.

Comment: I have updated my question. How can I create a string like the one in my question?